# Regex to get string inside apostrophe in wider string

Tags: php, regex, expression

I have this string:

```
$config['website'] = 'Devloooo';
```

And I need to get only the `Devloooo` (without apostrophes).

Only this text inside apostrophes.

I'm searching and looking for other regex on net and trying by http://regexr.com/ by I can't figure out how it should look like

All I got for now is `\$config\['website'] = '(.*?)';`

Comment: how about `\$config\['website'] = '([a-zA-Z]+)';` and also add which language you are using

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh it caches whole string

Comment: you can use groups https://regex101.com/r/N372ad/2

Comment: what do you mean in wider string, whats the criteria for matching?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh on var_dump it gives me int(0) after check, code http://wklej.to/ZItmY

Comment: @abstractnature It means I only need to catch this http://imgur.com/a/TJYaT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex would be `\].*'(.*)'`

Here is your program to find it

```
    Matcher m = (Pattern.compile("\\].*'(.*)'")).matcher("$config['website'] = 'Devloooo';");
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Console output:

```
Devloooo
```